# Facebook login: url cannot be loaded

Tags: facebook, authentication

I have the following code and get the following error (it is in Dutch):

Graph returned an error: URL kan niet worden geladen: Het domein van deze URL is niet toegevoegd aan de domeinen van deze app. Voeg alle domeinen en subdomeinen van je app toe aan het veld Appdomeinen in de instellingen van je app om deze URL te kunnen laden.

What may be wrong?

```
    ini_set('display_errors', true);
$host = "m.****.com"; // Your Sub domain
$host2 = "www.m.****.com"; // Your Sub domain
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == $host || $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == $host2) {
    $root_doc = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
        $root_doc = str_replace("/m","",$root_doc);
} else {
    $root_doc = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
}

include_once("$root_doc/php-graph-sdk-5.x/src/Facebook/autoload.php");


//require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'; // change path as needed

$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '*****',
  'app_secret' => '****',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
  //'default_access_token' => '{access-token}', // optional
]);

// Use one of the helper classes to get a Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken entity.
//   $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
//   $helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();
//   $helper = $fb->getCanvasHelper();
//   $helper = $fb->getPageTabHelper();

//BEGIN
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

//$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
if (isset($_GET['state'])) {
  $helper->getPersistentDataHandler()->set('state', $_GET['state']);
}


try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (! isset($accessToken)) {
  if ($helper->getError()) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
    echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
    echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
    echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
  } else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
    echo 'Bad request';
  }
  exit;
}

// Logged in
echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
var_dump($accessToken->getValue());

// The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens
$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

// Get the access token metadata from /debug_token
$tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
//echo '<h3>Metadata</h3>';
//var_dump($tokenMetadata);

// Validation (these will throw FacebookSDKException's when they fail)
$tokenMetadata->validateAppId("152670682069405");
// If you know the user ID this access token belongs to, you can validate it here
//$tokenMetadata->validateUserId('123');
$tokenMetadata->validateExpiration();

if (! $accessToken->isLongLived()) {
  // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
  try {
    $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
  } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $e->getMessage() . "</p>\n\n";
    exit;
  }

  echo '<h3>Long-lived</h3>';
  var_dump($accessToken->getValue());

}

$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
//END




try {
  // Get the \Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser object for the current user.
  // If you provided a 'default_access_token', the '{access-token}' is optional.
  $response = $fb->get('/me', '{access-token}');
} catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$me = $response->getGraphUser();
echo 'Logged in as ' . $me->getName();
```

I hope i will get an answer.

Regards,
Jeroen

Comment: Please research this properly, it has been asked about countless times. Switch your Facebook account language to English so that you also get the error message in English, if that helps searching.

Comment: @CBroe I think this is a legitimate question and I don't see an answer anywhere. 
I'm getting the same exact error and I'm not dutch, I don't speak dutch, and my facebook account is not dutch.  So 1) why is it giving me a random error in dutch, and 2) why does it only happen in live mode, when test mode works perfectly?

Answer (score 0):

Translated from Dutch to English:

URL can not be loaded: The domain of this URL has not been added to the domains of this app. Add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App domains field in your app's settings to load this URL.